# Can't find variable: Drupal

Tags: 8, javascript

I've created a behaviours in JS but when I'm not connected as admin it show in the console this error:

> Can't find variable: Drupal

When I write `console.log(Drupal)` in the console explorer it show too the error.

How I can fix this error ?

Edit :

I've defined my library by this way :

```
myc_facebook:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
    js/timeago.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

I integrate my library in a block by this way :

```
public function build() {
        $config = $this->getConfiguration();

        // Check if the conf
        if (empty($config['token']) || empty($config['pagename']) || empty($config['pageurl']) || empty($config['limit']))
            return array('err' => array('#markup' => t('You might configure this block.')));

        $build = [];
        // Create the wrapper to include facebook posts
        $build['facebook']['timeline']['#markup'] = '<div id="myc-fb-posts" class="slider"><ul class="slides"></ul></div>';
        // Push conf vars
        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['myc_fb'][$key] = $value;
        }
        // Includes libraries
        $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'myc_facebook/myc_facebook';

        return $build;
    }
```

Comment: You should post your code. Without your code is impossible to know what's wrong. Give as much information as you can.

Comment: For debugging switch off javascript aggregation, so that you can see which js files are loaded (or in your case are not loaded).

Comment: it's not code problem because on the explorer console when I write console.log(Drupal) it shows "Can't find variable: Drupal". Then for the anonymous user Drupal isn't load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're simply missing the dependency on core/drupal (and posibly also core/jquery) in your library, so that Drupal and JQuery get loaded, which by default it doesn't for anonymous users.

Comment: Check main post I updated

Comment: So you're missing the core/drupal dependency as @Berdir mentioned

Comment: `core/drupal` and `core/drupalSettings` are two different things. Add `core/drupal` as the first dependency and rebuild the cache and attach your libraries to the page.